# Aure APP SSL Complaint

Tags: azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-app-api

Recently we had a security scan for our one of the azure app and found that this was not security complaint . TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  cipher is weak and it should not be supported

could you please let me know if there is any way to solve this . have already left a feedback for this in azure portal

Answer (score 0):

The 3DES cipher suites were removed 2 months ago. If you run your report now, it will no longer be flagged.

Here is a report for one of my sites hosted on Azure Web Apps: [SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=kaushalp.azurewebsites.net&latest)

Do note the deadline for **PCI DSS 3.1** has been postponed until **June 30th 2018**.

You can also use App Service Environment. Here you can alter the cipher suite order and even disable TLS if needed. See this": [Change TLS cipher suite order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-custom-settings#change-tls-cipher-suite-order)

Below is a screenshot of the current list of supported cipher suites:
[image: Supported Cipher Suites in Azure Web Apps (July 2017)]